# Why use Rails public_method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am reading through Avdi Grimm's book 'Objects in Rails' and he uses the method public_method and I dont understand why.  Here is the code example:

```
class Blog
  # ...
  attr_writer :post_source
  # ...
  private
  def post_source
    @post_source ||= Post.public_method(:new)
  end
end
```

Why would you call Post.public_method(:new) and not Post.new?  Do these methods do anything different or are they exactly the same?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Post.new
```

is **not** equivalent to

```
Post.public_method(:new)
```

The former is an invocation of method `new`, which, by default, creates a new `Post` object. The latter, however, does *not* call `new` immediately. It merely prepares it to be called later. I haven't read that particular book, but if you look around in the associated source code, you'll see this line

```
@post_source.call # maybe some params are passed here
```

This is where `Post#new` finally gets called.

Documentation: [Object#public_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-public_method), [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method).

Comment: You were right about the call method and I know you havent read the book, but what could be a reason for calling new in this manner?  http://objectsonrails.com/#ID-a46ff338-26d8-41b9-b822-83388d08eef4

Comment: @jhamm: This looks like a Factory Method design pattern to me. There may be different methods that produce a `Post` object. `Post#new` is just one of them. By storing callable method reference in a `@post_source` variable we abstract from knowing what exactly that method is. All we need to know that it produces a `Post`. This is a common pattern in OOP. However, it's not normally used to create your regular domain objects (blog posts). It's just an illustration.

Comment: Or the reason could be banal deferred invocation. Or something else. I'm going to ping Avdi on twitter. :)

Answer (score 2):

`Post.public_method(:new)` and `Post.new` are different things. The latter creates an instance of `Post`. The former creates an instance of `Method`, which is not the result of applying such method but is an abstraction of the method itself. You can take out the result of it by doing `call` on it later.

`Post.public_method(:new)` may be replaced by `Post.method(:new)`, unless there is a private or protected method named `new`. It is just making sure not to refer to such methods if there are any.

Comment: "creates a method" - I have a feeling that this doesn't tell the OP a thing. :)

Comment: Why would you call 'new' in such a manner?  Why not just call Post.new?

Comment: One possible advantage is that the post will only really be created when it is actually used.

Comment: @nathanvda: one would still have to do `@post_source.call` for that. Not any better than `Post.new`.